# How can I convert a byte[] to an Array (and back) using C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

How can a byte[] instance be converted to an Array instance? And, how can I then convert an Array back to byte[]?

Comment: What language? What is the type of `array`? What is the type of `byte`?

Comment: @Theun: That's because I tagged it based on my assumption from looking at the username, duh.

Answer (score 1):

They are interchangeable:

```
Array array = new byte[10];
byte[] buffer = (byte[]) array;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that count as boxing of sorts?

Comment: No. byte array is a reference type anyway. Boxing happens if I cast `byte` (or any value type) as `object`.

Comment: This is wrong answer. Array in C# will never be interchangeable with byte[]

Comment: @Artur what?? Are you using C# 0.5? This code compiles to C# 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0...

Comment: @Artur Mustafin: Uh, you said in your answer that they're the same and so OP has "nothing to do", and now you're saying it's not true?